# Cannot resolve symbol 'Windows' Rider .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, bluetooth

Same as title when I try to use Windows.Devices.Bluetooth I get a “Cannot resolve symbol” error. Is there a way to add this assembly or a NuGet package with similar functionality?

I have tryed other net versions and even using net framework

Comment: What assembly or package? Have you done some research to find out where the type(s) you want to use is declared? What is that type(s) anyway? I'm assuming that `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth` is actually a namespace but your incomplete explanation of your problem doesn't specify.

Comment: The documentation for that namespace is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth?view=winrt-22621) and that indicates that it specifically relates to UWP. Are you creating a UWP app? You haven't tagged your question with UWP so either you're not and that's why you can't use it or you haven't included all the relevant tags. I don't use UWP myself but I would guess that it would be available by default if you were.

Comment: @DongLi, WPF, or UWP?